# Showing child when hovering parent doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I've put my code into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eschon/rnaju92k/1/) because I wasn't able to reproduce it with a smaller example.

I have a few menu items that show their submenu when hovered. I wanted to add a title that should also be shown on hover but the css class doesn't seem to work.

Here's the rule, it's on line 60 in the fiddle:

```
li:hover > .skimap-control-title {
  display: block;
}
```

The funny thing is if I add the exact same rule in the developer tools it suddenly works.

I hope someone here can help me.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Your example works the way I would expect it to work. Are you trying to take the title attribute and show it as text on the page instead of as a tooltip? If so then the only way to do that is with Javascript. To do it with just CSS you would have to have a span with text that would be hidden until the CSS rule triggers the visibility.

Comment: I agree with @markbernard - I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve here. I would agree with Mark for the most part; there are a number of ways you could go about it. But personally, I think a lot of your confusion would be cleared up by cleaning up your markup. If you can provide a more details, we should be able to help.

Comment: I just realised that I pointed to the wrong rule in my question. I updated it to show the right thing.

Comment: @markbernard I have a hidden span with the text. The rule that shows it is the one that is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it thanks to @cocoa

I just copied the rule after using "Tidy up" in my fiddle and replaced the rule in my css file and it works.

The strange thing is in the git diff the two lines look exactly the same.

[image]

I'm clueless what the difference is here, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with some syntax/formatting errors. I wasn't able to narrow it down, but when you click "Tidy Up" in JSFiddle, it seems to work as expected. See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ht2heppq/)

Also why do you have `<ul></ul>`? What is the point of these empty tags?

Comment: The menu gets generated from a template. If there is a submenu the items are put into the empty `<ul>`. There might be a way to write this so that the `<ul>` is only generated when there is a submenu but I didn't want to spend time figuring it out.

Comment: Also your right about the "Tidy Up", now I just have to figure out what it changes.

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing your code, we can only guess.

But here's an example on how to display a child when the parent is in hover state:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="show-on-hover">Hello there!</div>
</div>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
.outer {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.show-on-hover {
  display: none;
}

.outer:hover {
  background: #ccf;
}

.outer:hover .show-on-hover {
  display: block;
}
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/an5v2atn/1/